# I am stuck unpivoting query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

[image]

I have to Unpivot this table

I tried this

```
select * from unpivot2
unpivot (
( legendary,count)
  for type1 in ('Dragon', 'Psychic' , 'Fire')
) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is difficult to understand the `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` operators, simply use `UNION` and `GROUP BY` to implement the same.

Create your original pivoted table

```
CREATE TABLE pivot
(
    legendary   nvarchar(10),
    dragon      int,
    psychic     int,
    fire        int
);
```

Insert the records

```
INSERT INTO pivot values
('false',20,43,47),
('true',12,14,15);
```

Original table output

```
 SELECT * FROM pivot;
```

[image]

Create Unpivot table using the `UNION` operator.

```
CREATE TABLE unpivot AS
SELECT
    legendary,
    'dragon'    AS type1,
    dragon      AS value
FROM
    pivot
UNION
SELECT
    legendary,
    'psychic'   AS type1,
    psychic     AS value
FROM
    pivot
UNION
SELECT
    legendary,
    'fire'      AS type1,
    fire        AS value
FROM
    pivot
ORDER BY 
    type1;
```

Query unpivot output

```
 SELECT
    *
 FROM
    unpivot;
```

[image]

Pivoting back using the `UNION` and `GROUP BY` operators.

```
CREATE TABLE pivot AS
SELECT
    legendary,
    MAX(dragon)         AS  dragon,
    MAX(psychic)        AS  psychic,
    MAX(fire)           AS  value
FROM
(   
    SELECT
        legendary,
        value       AS      dragon,
        NULL        AS      psychic,
        NULL        AS      fire
    FROM
        unpivot
    WHERE
        type1='dragon'
    UNION
    SELECT
        legendary,
        NULL        AS      dragon,
        value       AS      psychic,
        NULL        AS      fire
    FROM
        unpivot
    WHERE
        type1='psychic'
    UNION
        SELECT
        legendary,
        NULL        AS      dragon,
        NULL        AS      psychic,
        value       AS      fire
    FROM
        unpivot
    WHERE
        type1='fire'
  
)set_union
GROUP BY legendary;
```

Query pivot output

```
SELECT * FROM pivot;
```

Output
[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Danish Sir Thanks for answering first I got an error which says Dragon invalid identifier then I also use " " on it but still it shows error  but when I run your query in SSMS it works. Any idea about this?